# Повторный запуск программы python

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, автозапуск

Приветствую всех. Есть скрипт который парсит exel лист и выводит мне нужную строку, работает хорошо. Но как сделать чтобы скрипт по завершению своей задачи начинал заново работать? вот сам скрипт

```
#!/usr/bin/python3    
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from xlrd import open_workbook
    from tn import *

    rb = open_workbook('/home/kocik/Рабочий стол/clients.xls')
    sheet_s = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
    sheet_o = rb.sheet_by_index(1)

    massiv=[]

    def value_dog():
        value = int()
        value = input("Введите номер договора:")
        try:
            valye=int(value)
            dalee=pars_client(value)
        except:
            print("Вероятно ошибка, попробуйте заново")
            ret=value_dog()


    def pars_client(value):


        for ii in range(sheet_s.nrows):#Парсим сокол
            data = sheet_s.cell_value(ii,0) 
            if int(value) == data or value == data:
                for i in range(sheet_s.ncols):
                    mass=sheet_s.cell_value(ii,i)
                    massiv.append(mass)
            else:
                continue

        for ii in range(sheet_o.nrows):#Парсим опытную и сырский
            data = sheet_o.cell_value(ii,0)
            if int(value) == data or value == data:
                for i in range(sheet_o.ncols):
                    massa = sheet_o.cell_value(ii,i)    
                    massiv.append(massa)
            else:
                continue

        #print(massiv)  
        if len(massiv)<1  :
            print ("Данного абонента нет в списке")
            ret=value_dog()
        else:
            vlan = int(massiv[1])
            switch = massiv[3]
            port = massiv[4]
            print ("################################################################\n""Улица "+massiv[6]+" "+str(massiv[7])+"-"+str(massiv[8])+"\n"+"Vlan: "+str(vlan)+', '+"Подключен на: "+str(switch)+' в '+str(port)+' порт')
            teln = telnet_connect(vlan,switch,port)


    def main():
        parses = value_dog()



    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

Если после teln = telnet_connect(vlan,switch,port) добавить parses = value_dog() то он продолжает работать, но после ввода номера делает операции по предыдущему номеру ввода. Где ошибка? и как сделать чтоб программа могла постоянно работать?

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть в бесконечный цикл (с условием выхода) часть функции `value_dog`, в которой производится ввод данных пользователем и вызов парсера. Тем самым, вы избавитесь от рекурсивного вызова и путаницы с областями видимости.

Comment: Я пока новичок в пайтоне, это мой второй скрипт, и не много не понял вас, не могли бы вы показать что именно в цикл обернуть?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from tn import *

rb = open_workbook('/home/kocik/Рабочий стол/clients.xls')
sheet_s = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet_o = rb.sheet_by_index(1)

massiv=[]

def value_dog():
    while True:
        value = input("Введите номер договора:")
        if int(value) == 0:
            break
        dalee = pars_client(value)

def pars_client(value):

    for ii in range(sheet_s.nrows):#Парсим сокол
        data = sheet_s.cell_value(ii,0) 
        if int(value) == data or value == data:
            for i in range(sheet_s.ncols):
                mass=sheet_s.cell_value(ii,i)
                massiv.append(mass)
        else:
            continue

    for ii in range(sheet_o.nrows):#Парсим опытную и сырский
        data = sheet_o.cell_value(ii,0)
        if int(value) == data or value == data:
            for i in range(sheet_o.ncols):
                massa = sheet_o.cell_value(ii,i)    
                massiv.append(massa)
        else:
            continue

    #print(massiv)  
    if len(massiv)<1  :
        print ("Данного абонента нет в списке")
    else:
        vlan = int(massiv[1])
        switch = massiv[3]
        port = massiv[4]
        print ("################################################################\n""Улица "+massiv[6]+" "+str(massiv[7])+"-"+str(massiv[8])+"\n"+"Vlan: "+str(vlan)+', '+"Подключен на: "+str(switch)+' в '+str(port)+' порт')
        teln = telnet_connect(vlan,switch,port)


def main():
    parses = value_dog()



if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```